# Embed a Tumblr post in my Google AMP page

Tags: php, php-5.3, amp-html

I am using PHP5. How do you embed a responsive Tumblr posts into an AMP page?

I have tried to use `amp-iframe` with the tag `layout="responsive"` but re-sizing the window causes either part of the post is covered or there is a lot of white space around the post.

Also, how would I get the width/height for a post so that I wouldn't have to manually change the dimensions every time I change the Tumblr embedding?

Comment: code formatted and tag added

Answer (score 0):

Please file a feature request at https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new